# Why there is lag in position of button when using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see in snippet when clicked on "Please agree" it take some time for `.termsAgreeButton` to come in its exact position .

Can this issue be fixed

> When "Please agree" is clicked button is somewhat above it's exact position with width less than expectedand comes to exact position with expected width after 0.5s or 1s

Also can you tell about how to fix `.termsAgreeButton` position so that it doesn't change its position when screen size changes

> Has to put `.termsAgreeButton` in fixed place so that when there is more terms than it remain in its position and data is scrolled without affecting it's position.

As the cause of this lag is `animation` can it possible to remove lag of button and animation still run.

**Let me know if you need clarification**

```js
function terms() { //terms and termsition dialog i.e, a link
  document.getElementById("terms").style.display = "flex";
  var ticker = document.getElementById("tickerOnCheckBox"); //to check whether checkbox is true or false

}

function termsClose() { //Terms close button
  document.getElementById("terms").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.terms {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
}

.termsBox {
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0% auto 0% auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid rgb(209, 208, 208);
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation: termsBoxZoom 0.3s linear;
}

@keyframes termsBoxZoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.4);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.termsModalHeading {
  position: sticky;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: rgb(18, 192, 204);
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
}

.termsText {
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.termsAgreeButton {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  top: 74.2%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0% 35% 0% 35%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(122, 238, 93);
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgb(229, 255, 222);
  color: rgb(122, 238, 93);
  transition: background-color 0.8s;
}

.termsAgreeButton:hover {
  background-color: rgb(129, 245, 100);
  border-color: rgb(129, 245, 100);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#me" id="checkBoxText" onclick="terms()">Please agree</a>

<div id="terms" class="terms">
  <div class="termsBox">
    <div class="termsModalHeading">
      <div class="modalHeading">Terms of Service</div>
      <button class="modalCloseButton" onclick="termsClose()">&#x2716;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="termsText">This is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis
      is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsitionThis is our terms and termsition </div>
    <button class="termsAgreeButton" id="termsAgreeButton" onclick="termsAgree()">I agree</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin percentage uses the width of its parent, not the height.
So your 12.5% is 12.5% of the card width.
You could use flexbox to center it.

```css
.card {
  /* display: none; */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cardBox {
  /* display: block; */
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 60vw;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 3px dashed crimson;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="cardBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can it possible to apply `animation` only on box while button has no effect of anime . As you can see in changed question the button lag

Comment: ??? You totally changed the question. You should have added a new question as now my answer has no relevance to the current question and is useless for anyone else who views the question in the future.